# Addition and multiplication of arrays/structures in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

```
K=12;
N=2;
phi_st=0;
delta_phi=30;

i=1:K;
phi(i)=phi_st+(i*delta_phi);
j=1:N;
phi_p=180;

phi_P=(phi_p)*(j-1);
phi_1=phi(i)+phi_P;
```

Now my question is how do I compute

phi_1=phi(i)+phi_P;

The error am getting is "Error using + Matrix dimensions must agree."

Please assist me.thanks

Comment: Read [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html) to learn how to use arrays in MATLAB. You are trying to add a 2 element array to a 12 element array. What was your intention?

Comment: My intention is to do add first element of the 2 element array to all elements of the 12 element array, then do the same with the second element. Thanks

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify this. I wrote you an answer. Be sure to read MATLAB's basics in the link I gave you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do:

```
phi_1 = phi(i) + phi_P(1);
phi_2 = phi(i) + phi_P(2);
```

Note that `(i)` is unnecessary here. You can also write:

```
phi_1 = phi + phi_P(1);
phi_2 = phi + phi_P(2);
```

If you want both results in a matrix you can concatenate them like this:

```
phi_both = [phi_1; phi_2];
```

Alternatively, you can do all the additions between the 12 elements array and the 2 element array in a single command, like this:

```
phi_both = bsxfun(@plus, phi, phi_P');
```

Comment: Thank you again Naveh. Let me implement this